# Can you set brightness adjustment by increment as default behavior? (macOS 13 Ventura)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

To adjust brightness by increments, you need to hold down <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Can you make it so that the brightness will adjust by increments by default without holding down <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

I'm on MacBook Air M2, running macOS 13 Ventura

Answer (score 3):

After searching around I discovered MonitorControl. It comes with a nice suite of features for controlling external monitors but it also has a way to let you adjust the macbook display by increments.

After installing the software, in the "**Keyboard**" tab, check the option "**Use fine OSD scale for brightness and contrast**"

[image: Screenshot]